# Use parent protocol default function implementation in sub protocol in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm looking for a way for subclassing a protocol and call a base function with a default implementation.

Let's say the following structure:

```
// My base protocol
protocol BaseProcotol {
  func display(message: String)
}

extension BaseProcotol {
  func display(message: String) {
    print(message)
  }
}

// The sub protocol
protocol SubProtocol : BaseProtocol { }

extension SubProtocol {
  func display(message: String) {
    display(message) // <- I cannot call the default BaseProcotol implem! 
    print("This message was sent from sub protocol.")
  }
}
```

In the following architecture I cannot manage to `SubProtocol` function `display(message:)` correctly because I end up with a infinite loop since the `SubProtocol` function calls itself and not the `BaseProcotol` function.

I tried to use something like:

```
extension SubProtocol {
  func display(message: String) {
    (self as BaseProtocol).display(message) // <- Still the same issue...
    print("This message was sent from sub protocol.")
  }
}
```

But it didn't work...

The only way I found to do this was a non elegant solution by adding a new function like this:

```
// The sub protocol
protocol SubProtocol : BaseProtocol { 
  func displaySubProtocol(message: String)
}

extension SubProtocol {
  func displaySubProtocol(message: String) {
    display(message) // <- works, call the BaseProtocol default implementation 
    print("This message was sent from sub protocol.")
  }
}
```

But as you can see I have to add an other function, plus if a class adopte the `SubProtocol` it could call the `BaseProtocol` function...

What could be a way of doing it well?

Comment: There's no way to tell Swift to "always call the default implementation of this protocol requirement" (default implementations don't always exist for requirements after all). If you want that kind of behaviour, you should factor out the implementation of `BaseProcotol`'s default implementation of `display(message:)` into another function, and then call that from both default implementations. Or you may want to consider using inheritance (w/ classes).

Comment: Suggestion: `extension SubProtocol where Self: BaseProtocol { }`. Not tested.

Comment: @valcanaia Thanks for your message but unfortunately it doesn't work, and get the same error plus this warning "Redundant conformance constraint 'Self': 'BaseProtocol'"